# Aerospike- Python Client- get host name from INFO_NODE

Tags: aerospike

looking for details of below questions.

1. Using INFO_NODE we are looking to build an UI interface to display something like (i net statistics) below.

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Network Information (2020-07-21 00:39:27 UTC)~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 Cluster                           Node               Node                  Ip       Build   Cluster   Migrations        Cluster     Cluster         Principal   Client     Uptime
    Name                              .                 Id                   .           .      Size            .            Key   Integrity                 .    Conns          .
test                   testbox.test.com:3000   *aaaaaaaaaaaa0   XX.XXX.XX>XXXX:3000   E-4.5.3.5         1      0.000     key12344    True     aaaaaaaaaaaa0        3   14:12:13
```

How can we get details of cluster name and node name.
we could get other details from INFO_NODE?

2. Can we run `quiesce`, `recluster` from python client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to issue any info command from a client. See this [Knowledge Base article](https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/how-do-i-run-asinfo-commands-from-the-client/1373). Getting any statistics or configuration parameter values can also be done through similar info calls. For example [node-id](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration/index.html?show-removed=1#node-id) or [cluster-name](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration/index.html?show-removed=1#cluster-name).

Comment: Info_node with request="statistics" can give us node and cluster name ?

Comment: For configuration, it would be using the get-config command. You can see examples under https://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/info/#get-config.

Comment: For example: root@d7af462a411d:/# asinfo -v 'get-config' -l | grep node
node-id=BB9030011AC4202
node-id-interface=null

Comment: Thank you.. is it possible to run INFO_NODE (python client)  to do something similar to 'asinfo -v 'quiesce:' with 10.10.100.10 ?'

Comment: Yes, you can issue any info command from the Python client so you can certainly issue the quiesce command through the info_node API call. I am not familiar with the exact syntax of info_node but I would expect it to just take quiesce: as the command.

Comment: I was able to issue Quiesce.. but not able to check status of Quiesce command. something similar to  "asadm -e 'show statistics like quiesce " can be done from python client ?

Comment: The `show statistics like quiesce` only works straight from asadm. From the client, you need to use proper fully formed `asinfo` commands. So in this case, you would use something like asinfo -h <host ip> -v 'statistics' -l  (or just statistics I guess form that client API) and then parse the output for the quiesce specific metric. The 'Examples' collapsed section at the top of the metrics reference manual has such syntax details: https://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/metrics/index.html

Comment: i had noticed it earlier. but these statistics are on NAMESAPACE level and would require looping thru all Namespace. Thank you for  direction.

Comment: Oh, then you can directly get namespace specific stats through "namespace/<namespace name>".

Comment: when i issue this for namespace - for some namespace it return unkown.. any reason ?   normal asinfo shows details of all NS. but python client return unkown.

Comment: So you are confirming it does work for some namespaces? If so, the only reason to return unknown for some namespaces would be that they don't exist. The namespace names (and set names) are case sensitive, make sure you are sending the right namespace name. Also, there are 2 commands: `namespaces` which returns all namespaces, and `namespace/<namespace_name>` for respective namespaces (notice the `s` at the end for the command returning all namespaces).